# Dynamically load layout in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, android-relativelayout

My application requires 2 screens and for this I have created two different `XML` layout files using `RelativeLayout`. One layout file loads whenever I run my Activity. Now I want to load the second layout on to the same `Activity` , when user click on a button in `OptionsMenu` and also when user press Back button the first screen loads instead of exiting the application. So that i don't need to create another `Intent` in my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally there should be two different activities present in your application. 
You can add or remove a view component in a view but if you are looking for two completely different screens then i would suggest you to go for a new activity.

I dint get what you meant by "and also when user press Bakc button the first screen loads instead of exiting the application"

If you dont want to show the first screen just finish() the activity.

Comment: I mean when I loads another Layout by calling setContentView() method again in my Activity and press Back(hardware button) then my application exits. Now I don't want to exit, instead i just want to load previous layout.

Comment: Have you got any specific reason/requirnment not going for two seperate activities? As this would be a natural behaviour of Activity stack. Say i am initially in activity A(XML 1 using setContentView)  and i launch an intent to move to activity B (XML 2 using setContentView). when i press a back key from Activity B , it automatically takes me to activity A (XML 1). Are you looking for anything different ?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try re-calling the setContentView?

Or you may prefer using the ViewFlipper,

Good example [here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-viewflipper-example/).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a rather simpler means.

Put both your layouts in the single XML and show/gone them appropriately as need be. I dont think u need anything more complicated :-)